# Unity The name 'PrefabUtility' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to build a Unity game, and keep getting the error:

> Assets\charaterselection.cs(34,9): error CS0103: The name 'PrefabUtility' does not exist in the current context

The issue is I imported UnityEditor, I'm not sure what's going on

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class charaterselection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer sr;
    public List<Sprite> skins = new List<Sprite>();
    private int selecectedSkin;
    public GameObject player;

    public void Next()
    {
        selecectedSkin=selecectedSkin+1;
        if (selecectedSkin== skins.Count)
        {
            selecectedSkin=0;
        }
        sr.sprite= skins[selecectedSkin];
    }

    public void back()
    {
        selecectedSkin = selecectedSkin - 1;
        if (selecectedSkin < 0)
        {
            selecectedSkin = skins.Count - 1;
        }
        sr.sprite = skins[selecectedSkin];
    }

    public void play()
    {
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(player, "Assets/Players/FROGY.prefab");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure this script resides in an "Editor" folder

Comment: Try closing VS and reopening, or regenerate the project files from Unity  `Edit` > `Preferences` > `External Tools` > `[Regenerate project files]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, I literately just made a file called "Editor" and it worked.